# Display user picture when available

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to display user account picture, if the picture field is not 'null' on the base.

If the field is 'null' i would display the default account picture.

I tried with `{{ if MYFIELD is null }}` and `{{ if MYFIELD is define }}`

Like this

```
<img src="{% if user.pictureName is null %}{{ asset('bundles/nastycodefront/img/userpic.png') }}{% else %}{{ asset('uploads/pictures/nastypic_' ~ post.member ~ '.jpg') }}{% endif %}" alt="Profile Picture">
```

or

```
<img src="{% if user.pictureName is define %}{{ asset('uploads/pictures/nastypic_' ~ post.member ~ '.jpg') }}{% else %}{{ asset('bundles/nastycodefront/img/userpic.png') }}{% endif %}" alt="Profile Picture">
```

But all of this keep trying to get the custom image.

Do you have idea to fix this ? Is my code wrong ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Make an image attribute with the full URL and use the [default filter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/default.html) on it.

Comment: you've missed a "d" in `define` `{% if user.pictureName is defined %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<img src="{% if app.user.pictureName is defined and app.user.pictureName|length > 0 %}{{ asset('uploads/pictures/nastypic_' ~ app.user.pictureName ~ '.jpg') }}{% else %}{{asset('bundles/nastycodefront/img/userpic.png') }}{% endif %}"/>
```

Another elegant way is using default filter:

```
<img src="{{ app.user.pictureRoute|default('route to userpic.png') }}"/>
```